# Material not rendering right despite texture being correctly unwrapped?

Tags: rendering, materials, uv, shaders

That was a long title, but my problem is simple. I have some objects with a brick material which looks different when you look at it on "solid" mode with display set to "textured" (left) compared to "material preview" mode (right):

[image][image]

The part that looks stretched out is a different material than the normal brick material which I applied to th rest of the faces. Why is it causing this effect?